# react navigtaion Tab Bar not working after update to version 2.x

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

After updating react native and react navigation my tabbar stopped navigating to the different screens on tap. This broke for all three: `createTabNavigator`, `createBottomTabNavigator` and `createMaterialBottomTabNavigator`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it stopped working was that i was overriding `tabBarOnPress` whose API changed.

The new API of `tabBarOnPress` for `createBottomTabNavigator` and `createMaterialBottomTabNavigator` passes an object as an argument which contains `defaultHandler`. This needs to be called when overriding `tabBarOnPress`.

e.g.:

```
tabBarOnPress: obj => {
  // ... do your custom stuff
  obj.defaultHandler() // <- this handles navigation etc.
}
```